# Automation execution is too slow in chrome using selenium webdriver 36

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Earlier I was using `chrome 32`, which was very fast. But after upgrading to `36`, it is very slow. It is taking more than a second to execute sendKeys instruction even after location element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be the following if you use 64-bit OS architecture on your PC - as far as I remember is because Selenium performs switching between 32-bit and 64-bit mode (which is very slow operation). ChromeDriver was supported only in 32-bit. I had same issues with IE driver too.

***Update:***

Next thing to check then is that the proxy and network settings in chrome have not been altered. In the begging I considered extensions and add-ons, but Selenium raises **clean** instance each time. As to #36 being slow - check the dev threads on google chrome, you will see the issue has been ongoing for well over 6mths and is affecting cross-platforms too. And one solution is try disabling hardware acceleration.... it was a tenfold improvement for me on my laptop. 
To disable it... type "chrome:settings" in the address bar, click Advanced Settings, then uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available" under the System header. Close all open Chrome browser instances and restart Chrome.

Comment: But why was it faster earlier(I didn't change my OS though) ?

Comment: Still a problem for me using Windows 2008 Server 64Bit